# $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is generated by the subgroups $\text{im }i_{j*}$, where $i_j : (U_j, x_0) \rightarrow (X, x_0)$ is the inclusion

Tags: algebraic-topology

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

> Let $X$ be a space with basepoint $x_0$, and let $\{U_j | j \in J\}$ be an open cover of $X$ by path connected subspaces such that:
>
> $(1) x \in U_j$ for all $j \in J$.
>
> $(2) U_j \cap U_k$ is path connected for all $j,k$.
>
> Then $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is generated by the subgroups $\text{im }i_{j*}$, where $i_j : (U_j, x_0) \rightarrow (X, x_0)$ is the inclusion and $i_{j*} = \pi_1(i_j)$.
>
> (Hint) Use the Lebesgue number of the open cover $\{f^{-1}(U_j): j \in J\}$ of $I$ the interval $[0,1]$

I'm assuming the hint has something to do with setting up a chain of overlapping intervals of diameter less than $\delta$ (Lebesgue number for the open cover) in $I$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  I can see that I need to show that for every $[f] \in \pi_1(X, x_0)$, $[f] = \large(*)_{j \in J}[i \circ g_j]$ for some collection of $[g_j] \in \pi_1(U_j, x_0)$ for $j \in J$.

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: I presume that in (1) you mean $x_0 \in U_j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary element of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$, represented by a path $f: [0,1] \to X$ with $f(0)=f(1)=x_0$, consider $\{\gamma^{-1}(U_j) \mid j \in J\}$, which is an open cover of $[0,1]$, and let $\lambda > 0$ be a Lebesgue number for that open cover.

Pick an integer $K > \lambda$, and subdivide $[0,1]$ to $K$ subintervals of length $1/K$ with endpoints $0=x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_K = 1$. For each $k=1,...,K$ there exists some $j_k \in J$ such that $[x_{k-1},k_i] \subset f^{-1}(U_{j_k})$, and therefore $f[x_{k-1},x_k] \subset U_{j_k}$.

Let $p_k = f(x_k)$, so $p_0=p_n=x_0$, and if $1 \le k \le K-1$ then $p_k \in U_{j_k} \cap U_{j_{k+1}}$. Choose $h_k : [0,1] \to U_{j_k} \cap U_{j_{k+1}}$ to be a path with $g_k(0)=p_k$ and $g_k(1)=x_0$.

Decompose the path $f$ into a concatenation
$$f = f_1 * ... * f_K
$$
where $f_k$ is (a reparameterization of) $f \mid [x_{k-1},x_k]$.

Now prove that $f_1 * ... * f_K$ is path homotopic to
$$\underbrace{f_1 * h_1}_{g_1} * \underbrace{\bar h_1 * f_2 * h_2}_{g_2} * \cdots * \underbrace{\bar h_{K-1} * f_{K-1} * h_K}_{g_{K-1}} * \underbrace{\bar h_K * f_K}_{g_K}
$$
This gives the sequence of elements $[g_k] \in \pi_1(U_{j_k},x_0)$ you need to finish the proof.